# Sampling a 2D Matrix while keeping size of original matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am working on Probabilistic Matrix Factorization. I am wanting to divide the ratings matrix into train and validation. The code I have seen is NOT a random sample.

I have been trying to figure out how to do this.

For a simple example sake, the original matrix R is (10,10). I am looking for a train matrix that is a (10,10) but only has, lets say 70% randomly sampled of the values of matrix R with everything else being 0. and the validations matrix also being (10,10) but having the left over 30% of values with the rest being 0.

The key thing here is keeping the matrices the same size.

Anyone know how to do this?

edit:
thinking about it more: TrainingMatrix + ValidationMatrix = Matrix R if you do an elementwise addition

Comment: I don't see the problem. A matrix consists of dimensions and entries. Ask for the nonzero-entries and partition those into 70% and 30%. The former are 7 triples of `(dim_index_a, dim_index_b, value)` and the latter are 3 triples of the same. I would not look at the matrix-view, but at the *rating-view* = *sparse-matrix nnz view*. Compare with [scipy.sparse.coo_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html)

Comment: thanks sascha. working on this now. the real "gotcha" was when you do indeed have a sparse martix and you only want to sample the positions that have values.

Answer (score 0):

My solution. Let me know if there is a easier/faster way to do this.

```
import copy

#Figuring out Matrix Sampling
np.random.seed(3)
training_percent = .7

R = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
print("R:")
print(R)


#Get the indexes of the non-zero elements
non_zero_is,non_zero_js = np.nonzero(R)

#Randomly sample the indexes
sampled_indexes_of_non_zeros = np.random.choice(len(i), 
    int(np.floor(training_percent * len(i))), replace=False)

#Training Mask
training_mask = np.zeros(R.shape,dtype=bool)
for position in sampled_indexes_of_non_zeros:
    training_mask[non_zero_is[position],non_zero_js[position]] = True

#Training Matrix
training_matrix = R.copy()
training_matrix[~training_mask] = 0
print("\ntraining_martix:")
print(training_matrix)

#Validation Matrix
validation_matrix = R.copy()
validation_matrix[training_mask] = 0
print("\nvalidation_martix:")
print(validation_matrix)
```